# issue with iframe height

Tags: facebook, iframe, height

I know this topic has been asked about and answered multiple times but please believe that I have spend many hours searching for help and answers that work and/or I can actually understand.

It's the same ol' issue:
I have figured out how to add a custom tab and even a custom icon for it (and I am really happy to have been able to do even that!).
But, as per many other requests for help, it has the dreaded scroll bars.
I, like the others, want it to flow down past it's limited 800px size.
I have several different fixes for this, some I have tried unsuccessfully and some just go right over my head and I do not understand what is being written at all, where it goes and what needs to be edited in it.

I would really appreciate someone taking the time to walk me through the process and explaining the what's and how to's please.

View page here: http://www.bronts.com/bronts_facebook/index.html

View page within facebook here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/brontscom/191839754181703

Comment: any HTML codes please. too abstract to think of your layout.

Comment: added them in just now - thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use javascript sdk to autosize the iframe in a pagetab app.  You will need to have an application id for this.  Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

the FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();  sets the height of the canvas.

here is working example on my app. http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=135669679827333&sk=app_135669679827333

NOTE:  setAutoResize(); will be changing to setAutoGrow();

ALSO:  you may need to reduce the width of your image, not sure until auto size is in place.

---------- i use this and add just below the < body > tags of my documents.

```
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : 'Your-App-Id-Here',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    //channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
/* sets auto size to app canvas and page tab app. */
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
```

Comment: let me know if you have any more questions or need more assistance i will be online here for a while longer.

Comment: Thank you. I presume  that 'Your-App-Id-Here' becomes my app id # (and without the ' ') right? AND 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html' will be 'http://www.bronts.com/bronts_facebook/index.html' (and without the ' ')?

Comment: And does this change from // channel.html file to       // index.html ?

Comment: i opted out of the channel.html param but you can set it up  MORE HERE: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Comment: Thank you! Your help has been very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `body` and use [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to navigate inside iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({ appId: '1375268019431848', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
</script>
```

Comment: care to describe what you are doing here? Adding code doesn't mean people will understand what your approach to resolving the problem is....